# Erro de compilação ao usar string.Join

Tags: c#

Estou escrevendo um código de exemplo de busca binária que encontrei em um livro e recebo o seguinte erro do compilador:

> CSI 503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'
> CSI 503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int[l' to 'string'

[Imagem com os erros do compilador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skMuT.png)

O erro ocorre nesta linha:

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', sortedArr));
```

Ao alterar essa linha para:

```
Console.WriteLine("," + sortedArr);
```

O compilador não aponta erro, mas não tenho a saída esperada. A saída dele deveria ser `null` mas é:

> ,System.Int32[]

Como posso corrigir isso?

Código completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SelectionSort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new int[] { 4, 5, 1, 3, 10, 9, 6, 8, 7, 2 };
            var sortedArr = SelectionSort(numbers);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', sortedArr));
        }

        private static int[] SelectionSort(int[] array)
            => SelectionSort(new LinkedList<int>(array)).ToArray();

        private static IEnumerable<int> SelectionSort(LinkedList<int> list)
        {
            var minList = new LinkedList<int>();
            var maxList = new LinkedList<int>();

            while (list.Count != 0)
            {
                var min = list.Min();
                list.Remove(min);
                minList.AddLast(min);

                var max = list.Max();
                list.Remove(max);
                maxList.AddFirst(max);
            }

            return minList.Union(maxList);
        }
    }
}
```

Minha tentativa de corrigir:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SelectionSort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new int[] { 4, 5, 1, 3, 10, 9, 6, 8, 7, 2 };
            var sortedArr = SelectionSort(numbers);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', sortedArr));
        }

        private static int[] SelectionSort(int[] array)
            => SelectionSort(new LinkedList<int>(array)).ToArray();

        private static IEnumerable<int> SelectionSort(LinkedList<int> list)
        {
            var minList = new LinkedList<int>();
            var maxList = new LinkedList<int>();

            while (list.Count != 0)
            {
                var min = list.Min();
                list.Remove(min);
                minList.AddLast(min);

                var max = list.Max();
                list.Remove(max);
                maxList.AddFirst(max);
            }

            return minList.Union(maxList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP, o @AugustoVasques tem razão no comentário. Seu problema não tem nenhuma relação com o algoritmo de busca binária. Eu tomei a liberdade de editar a sua pergunta pra focar no real problema, criei um título que faz sentido no contexto do problema e alterei as tags. Use isso como base para a escrita de novas perguntas, isso ajuda as pessoas que querem responder a focar no que realmente é importante.

Answer (score 1):

Até o .NET Core 1.1 (isso inclui todas as versões de .NET Framework) o método `String.Join` **não tem** uma sobrecarga onde o primeiro parâmetro é um `char`, por isso você vê este erro de compilação.

Pra resolver, use o método `Join` que espera uma `string` como primeiro parâmetro.

```cs
string.Join(",", sortedArr);
```

[Documentação do método Join no .NET Framework 4.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8.1)
[Documentação do método Join no .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-2.0)